# How to change the webview background color with phonegap on iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I recently upgraded from phonegap CLI 4.1.2 (cordova build version 3.7.0) to CLI 6.0.1 (cordova build version 4.0.1) I can see while the phonegap webview bounce works on iOS but there is a background color that can be seen underneath the app content when the bounce happens. This color has changed from black to grey after the upgrade.

How can I change this background color which I assume is the webview background color. I tried to browse through `MainViewController` and `AppDelegate` Classes/files but did not find a place where the grey color is being set. This definitely is not the color of the `<body>` element.

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create a simple plugin. When your plugin is initialized, you can set the background color. For example:

```
- (void)pluginInitialize
{
    self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using cordova `config.xml` you can set a preference for the background color you want the main WebView to have, f.e.:

```
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff0000ff"/>
```

It supports a four-byte hex value, with the first byte representing the alpha channel, and standard RGB values for the following three bytes.

Read more here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#preference